# check for duplicates in arraylist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have an arraylist that contains items called Room. Each Room has a roomtype such as kitchen, reception etc.
I want to check the arraylist to see if any rooms of that type exist before adding it to the list.
Can anyone recommend a neat way of doing this without the need for multiple foreach loops?

(.NET 2.0)

---

I havent got access to the linq technology as am running on .net 2.0. I should have stated that in the question.
Apologies

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would not use `ArrayList` here; since you have .NET 2.0, use `List<T>` and all becomes simple:

```
List<Room> rooms = ...
string roomType = "lounge";
bool exists = rooms.Exists(delegate(Room room) { return room.Type == roomType; });
```

Or with C# 3.0 (still targetting .NET 2.0)

```
bool exists = rooms.Exists(room => room.Type == roomType);
```

Or with C# 3.0 and either [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) or .NET 3.5:

```
bool exists = rooms.Any(room => room.Type == roomType);
```

(the `Any` usage will work with more types, not just `List<T>`)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!rooms.Any (r => r.RoomType == typeToFind /*kitchen, ...*/))
  //add it or whatever
```

Comment: ah my apologies am running on .net 2 unfortunately

Comment: @OJ: with 2.0, only if you use LINQBridge... Any is provided by .NET 3.5; you could use the Exists syntax with C# 3.0 lambdas, however

Comment: Ah, the "Any" method ducked under my radar ;) But you don't need to use Any, you could use Find, which doesn't require LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it's not 100% clear to me if you want to enforce the rule that there may be only one room of a given type, or if you simply want to know.

If you have the invariant that no collection of `Room`s may have more than one of the same `Room` type, you might try using a `Dictionary<Type, Room>`.

This has the benefit of not performing a linear search on add.

You would add a room using the following operations:

```
if(rooms.ContainsKey(room.GetType()))
{
   // Can't add a second room of the same type
   ...
}
else
{
   rooms.Add(room.GetType(), room);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought using lists and doing Exists where an operation that takes `O(n)` time.
Using `Dictionary` instead is `O(1)` and is preferred if memory is not a problem.

If you do not need the sequential List I would try using a `Dictionary` like this:

```
Dictionary<Type, List<Room>> rooms = new Dictionary<Type, List<Room>>;

void Main(){
  KitchenRoom kr = new KitchenRoom();
  DummyRoom dr = new DummyRoom();
  RoomType1 rt1 = new RoomType1();
  ... 

  AddRoom(kr);
  AddRoom(dr);
  AddRoom(rt1);
  ...

}

void AddRoom(Room r){
  Type roomtype = r.GetType();
  if(!rooms.ContainsKey(roomtype){ //If the type is new, then add it with an empty list
   rooms.Add(roomtype, new List<Room>);
  }
  //And of course add the room.
  rooms[roomtype].Add(r);
}
```

You basically have a list of different roomtypes. But this solution is only OK if you don't need the arraylist. But for large lists this will be the fastest one.

I had a solution once with `List<string>` with 300.000+ items. Comparing each element with another list of almost the same size took humongous 12hrs to do. Switched the logic to using Dictionary instead and down to 12 minutes. For larger lists I always go `Dictionary<mytype, bool>` where bool is just a dummy not being used.

Answer (score 0):

Without using lambda expressions:

```
void AddRoom(Room r, IList<Room> rooms, IDictionary<string, bool> roomTypes)
{
   if (!roomTypes.Contains(r.RoomType))
   {
      rooms.Add(r);
      roomTypes.Add(r.RoomType, true);
   }
}
```

It doesn't actually matter what the type of the value in the dictionary is, because the only thing you're ever looking at is the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to sort the array, then walk the elements until you find a pair of adjacent duplicates. Make it to the end, and the array is dupe-free.